# why toplink creates multiple connections and uses different connections for reading and writing?

Tags: java, connection, toplink

i have a strange doubt, why toplink creates multiple connection while loading, and why it uses two different connections for reading and writing purposes on database??

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Are you using TopLink in a desktop/standalone applicatiion, or in a web application?

Multiple connections are usually used in connection pooling setup in web apps, with the intention of mitigating the DB connection time. The pool and the container takes care to reuse connections without closing them.

The different connections to read/write are used for scaling. Usually databases are more frequently read from than written to, hence one can scale more easily if read-only database mirrors/shards/replications are available to handle the read requests, and the main database only handles the write/modification requests (passing those to the read-only replications, of course).